# Alternative Knockout syntax?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, knockoutjs

Today I've noticed an alternative syntax in a `html`-template in Magento 2, which I hadn't noticed before. If you take a look at the [checkout/shipping template](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html), you'll notice a syntax like:

```
<each if="!quoteIsVirtual" args="getRegion('customer-email')" render="" />
<each args="getRegion('address-list')" render="" />
<each args="getRegion('address-list-additional-addresses')" render="" />

<!-- Address form pop up -->
<if args="!isFormInline">
    <button type="button"
            class="action action-show-popup"
            click="showFormPopUp"
            visible="!isNewAddressAdded()">
        <span translate="'New Address'" />
    </button>
    <div id="opc-new-shipping-address"
         visible="isFormPopUpVisible()"
         render="shippingFormTemplate" />
</if>
```

This is changed in [a commit made over a year ago](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/8648968bc5dff3d903ec0f9d693cf3d3761d23b1#diff-d65231b39819f1a6eb6fa1b6347e3434), where you can see the original equivalents, but I've only seen this until just now. Is this something I missed? Is it Knockout? Something Magento specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is an extension to the knockout base syntax:

See https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/ui_comp_guide/concepts/magento-bindings.html for more details

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about that one.